# Bash script to output function result

Tags: bash, scripting, hudson, jenkins

I have a bash shell script executed by Jenkins / Hudson. For some reason when I create a function, the output of that function is not logged back to the console. This is an example of my code:

**EDIT!!!** - this culprit here is SSH... Is there a way to force its output back to console?

```
perform_task()
{
   ssh jenkins@192.168.100.5 pwd
}

echo "Starting a task";
perform_task || { echo "The Task Failed"; exit 1; }
```

The output in the console is:

"Starting a task"

if I move the commands outside of the function, I can see their output.

Help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I partially solved the problem by getting the script to echo the command:

**#!/bin/bash -ex**

This still hides the output of that command, but at least I have insights about what's being run

Comment: maybe it is related to ';', you might want to replace it with '&&'. You might be 'exit'-ing before you 'echo'.

Answer (score 3):

I just copied your function, added `#!/bin/bash -e` to the beginning of and pasted it into the "Execute Shell" of Jenkins.

It worked fine!

Is your bash executable actually located at `/bin`? What OS are you running the script on?

```
Building remotely on slave_1
[test] $ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/hudson1206345540964396738.sh
+ echo 'Starting a task'
Starting a task
+ perform_task
+ ssh slave_2 pwd
/home/jenkins
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: For some reason the only way I got this to work is by adding -x

Comment: Actually that just echo's the command and not the output of the command.... I am correcting the original example, I think the problem here is SSH :-X

Comment: SSH keys are fine, I am able to execute the commands, just no ouput... I feel like the output is not being properly redirected, but not sure what to do about that

Comment: Just posted my output. Not sure what is going wrong with your redirection. FYI, Jenkins 1.419, and I removed the `"jenkins@"` portion, just had `ssh slave_2 pwd`

Comment: Something must be wrong with my redirection... Where would I check that?

Comment: Jenkins automatically redirects all output (stdout and stderr) directly to console. That should be working correctly otherwise you would get no output at all - not even without the function. Sorry mate, not sure what's going on, unless you have other symptoms. Will post if I find something else..

Comment: I appreciate the help! I'm at loss also

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Jenkins or all that, but this worked for me:

```
perform_task()
{
    ls -al
    ps aux
    pwd
}

echo "Starting a task"
perform_task || ( echo "The Task Failed" ; exit 1 )
```

Comment: Even with all the fixes? hrm. Weird. You are certain this script is being executed as a bash script?

Comment: Which fixes? The ; after exit?

Comment: Everything works 100%, just no output to the console of stuff inside the function. The commands get executed, but not displayed

Answer (score 0):

add `#!/bin/bash` as first line of the file
The reason is the basic *bourne shell*(/bin/sh) does not support some of the features you use.

Comment: make sure that the file is in _unix text format_ (only \n as new line)

Comment: what is `-e`?                                                       x

Comment: It's in Jenkins, so there is no file format discrepancy... The script works, just no output outside of function. Everything inside the function is being executed, but the output goes to /dev/null

Comment: -e means exit if any function inside exits with non-zero status